# With nested routes does the parent controller or the child controller process the request for the "new" action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-resources

If you have a nested resource defined like this:

```
map.resources :magazines, :has_many => :ads.
```

for these models:

```
class Magazine < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :ads 
end 

class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :magazine 
end
```

When you invoke this url:

```
/magazines/1/ads/1/new
```

with the nested route helper:

```
new_magazine_ad_path
```

**Which controller handles this `new` action: the `magazines` controller or the `ads` controller?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rake routes` to see a list of all your routes including their names where applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to read through section 3.8 on the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) but if I am correct (and as the guide suggests) it is the `Ads` controller.

Comment: The table in Section 3.8 directly below the example shows the different URL to controller mappings and there is one for "/magazines/1/ads/new" that points to "Ads" as the controller. I believe this is what you are asking.

Comment: To be a bit clearer: I believe "/magazines/1/ads/new" and "/magazines/1/ads/1/new" route to the same thing. You may just get to know what ad the user was on when they asked to create a new one with the second version.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the controller mappings in the table.